# Modify Existing d3 code - dynamic rectangle height to match text

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am working with the code at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jey/details/jmClJ) as a base to build a Gantt Chart for my needs.  However, I am trying to modify the code so that the actual Rectangle heights accommodate the text that is given to them.  In the example shown, all of the task texts are one word long so they fit within the rectangle.  However, if a task is several words long and the rectangle width is short, the text does not wrap and overflows.

How could I modify the code so that the rectangle heights are drawn to fit the text within them, or alternatively have the text wrap and have the rectangle grow (in height) to accommodate the text?

Right now the rectangle heights are hard-coded in the CodePen example:

```
var barHeight = 20;
```

The example also adds the text in the following way to the rectangles (see below).  I've experimented with trying to put html in the rectangle instead of text to no avail:

```
 var rectText = rectangles.append("text")
               .text(function(d){
                return d.task;
               })
```

Comment: you probably want to use `.getBBox()` on the element that you want to wrap, and then set the `width` and `height` of the `rect` to match.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. When/where would I call .getBBox() in the code?

Comment: Where is your code, ie. the modified example you mention above, and what have you already tried?

Answer (score 3):

You are really asking two questions.  One, how do you wrap the text and then two, how do you scale the rect height to that wrapped text.

1.) The canonical example of wrapping text is presented by M. Bostock [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).

2.) To scale the height of the rect to the text then, you can use `.getBBox()` as @BenLyall hints at.  You first wrap the text, then call `.getBBox()` on the text node and apply the height to the rect.

Here's a complete example:

```
var someWidth = Math.random() * 250;

var longText = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country";

 var rect = g.append('rect')
    .style('fill','steelblue')
    .attr('width', someWidth) //<-- random width we don't know it
    .attr('height', 1); // <-- start with arbitrary height

  var txt = g.append('text')
    .text(longText) //<-- our super long text
    .attr('x', 4)
    .attr('y', 10)
    .attr('dy', '.71em')
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .call(wrap, someWidth); //<-- wrap it according to our width

  var height = txt.node().getBBox().height + 15; //<-- get our height plus a margin
  rect.attr('height', height); //<-- change our rect
```

Here's a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEgzdTRw7DV6MoH09hJq?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of the example that you linked to.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdyGGp

The interesting bits:

```
var innerRects = rectangles.append("g")
             .attr("class", "rectangle");

  innerRects.append("rect")
             .attr("rx", 3)
             .attr("ry", 3)
             .attr("x", function(d){
              return timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime)) + theSidePad;
              })
             .attr("y", function(d, i){
                return i*theGap + theTopPad;
            })
             .attr("width", function(d){
                return (timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.endTime))-timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime)));
             })
             //.attr("height", theBarHeight)
             .attr("stroke", "none")
             .attr("fill", function(d){
              for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
                  if (d.type == categories[i]){
                    return d3.rgb(theColorScale(i));
                  }
              }
             })


         var rectText = innerRects.append("text")
               .text(function(d){
                return d.task;
               })
               .attr("x", function(d){
                return (timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.endTime))-timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime)))/2 + timeScale(dateFormat.parse(d.startTime)) + theSidePad;
                })
               .attr("y", function(d, i){
                  return i*theGap + 14+ theTopPad;
              })
               .attr("font-size", 11)
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .attr("text-height", theBarHeight)
               .attr("fill", "#fff");

  innerRects.each(function(r) {
    var bBox = d3.select(this).select("text").node().getBBox();
    d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("height", function(d) {
      return bBox.height;
    }).attr("y", function(d) {
      return bBox.y;

    });
  });
```

Instead of just appending the `rect` and `text` elements directly into a single group, I've created a new group for each one, so that they can be linked together, since for each `rect` we need to find out the `height` of it's corresponding `text` element.

After the `rect` and `text` elements have been created, I'm then looping over the `g` elements that I created and getting the bounding box (`getBBox()` function call) of the text and setting the `height` of the associated `rect` element to the `height` value returned from the bounding box.  I'm also setting the `y` element of the `rect` to match.

Additionally, the new `g` elements to group the `rect` and `text` elements together break the tooltip positioning code, so that is updated accordingly with:

```
innerRects.on('mouseover', function(e) {
         var tag = "";

         if (d3.select(this).data()[0].details != undefined){
          tag = "Task: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].task + "<br/>" + 
                "Type: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].type + "<br/>" + 
                "Starts: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].startTime + "<br/>" + 
                "Ends: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].endTime + "<br/>" + 
                "Details: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].details;
         } else {
          tag = "Task: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].task + "<br/>" + 
                "Type: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].type + "<br/>" + 
                "Starts: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].startTime + "<br/>" + 
                "Ends: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].endTime;
         }
         var output = document.getElementById("tag");
         var item = d3.select(this).select("rect").node();
         var x = (item.x.animVal.value + item.width.animVal.value/2) + "px";
         var y = item.y.animVal.value + 25 + "px";

         output.innerHTML = tag;
         output.style.top = y;
         output.style.left = x;
         output.style.display = "block";
       }).on('mouseout', function() {
         var output = document.getElementById("tag");
         output.style.display = "none";

 });
```

The changes here are :

```
     var item = d3.select(this).select("rect").node();
     var x = (item.x.animVal.value + item.width.animVal.value/2) + "px";
     var y = item.y.animVal.value + 25 + "px";
```

Previously, this was using `this` to grab the `x` and `y` positions of the `rect` elements.  Since these are now grouped with a `text` the code needs to be updated to reference the `rect` child element from the group.  This code does just that.

There are a whole bunch more issues when you start wrapping the text as well.  The background rectangles will also need to grow dynamically to contain them.  I'd suggest refactoring the example to deal with this.

You'll need to do the following:

1. Add placeholder elements for all the `rect`s.  For the background and task `rect`s, you should be able to set their `width` in advance (the background `rect` widths are just the width of the containing element.  The width of the task `rect`s are set by the start and end date of the tasks.
2. Using the `width` of the task `rect`s you can add the text elements and wrap at the appropriate width. (This example may help in doing that http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)
3. Go back and set the `height`s of all of the background and task `rect`s based on the computed `height`s of all their children `text` elements.

Comment: I clicked on your CodePen link and modified the "task" of the first element in the taskArray to be "task: "conceptualize to be or not to be that is the question" and it is not wrapping nor is the rectangle height growing.  Am I doing something wrong?